# My Redmi 2 Prime's battery usage is inconsistent after OS reinstalls

Tags: battery, battery-life, xiaomi

Recently after I updated my phone to MIUI7 the battery increased from 9 hours internet browsing backup to 10 hours and 4 minutes for Internet Browsing backup. But after I tried to roll back the OS to MIUI 6 and few older ROMs of MIUI 7 and them wiped and reset the phone OS to the latest MIUI 7.1.1.0, I have lost some amount of battery and now it gives a Internet Browsing backup of about 8 hours. How can I fix this, has anything wrong happened to the phone because I formatted my phone too many times (at least 6 times as I remember). Please Help.

Comment: You should understand that battery usage can differ due to various other reasons too. Were you browsing the same websites and for the same amount of time? Also, Chrome (or whatever your browser is) may have been updated and some features may have been enabled/disabled which can affect battery regardless of flashes. This is totally unimportant. BTW, an online battery backup of 8 hours is considered very good battery backup. You need not worry at all.

Comment: Battery runtimes are based on information in the batterystats file, this file is wiped on a reinstall and it takes some time to for it "rebuild" information and come up with consistent battery run-times, especially in larger capacity batteries. There is typically considered to be a 2-3 full charge cycle delay (2-3 days for most people) before the times are considered roughly accurate.